# Unsupported class version error on Java Eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

my eclipse editor had an error in the last 2 days, but never before. It says

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/pluginswithalfa/java/takeinandout has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 53.0
```

I use MacOS and i am a newbie could someone please help me

Comment: A class has been compiled with Java 15 (class file version 59) but the editor code only supports up to Java 9 (class file version 53).

Comment: Oh I see the issue, But how can I upgrade my eclipse editor to edit java 15?

Comment: What is this 'eclipse editor'? Are you just trying to look at a class file using the standard Eclipse class editor? You would have to update to the current Eclipse 2020-12 which is the first version to have full Java 15 support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)